# Converting an existance proof of an infinite series to a function that gives that infinite series

Tags: coq

I'm trying to reason on a TRS, and I have ran into the following proof obligation:

```
  infinite_sequence : forall t' : Term,
                      transitive_closure R t t' ->
                      exists t'' : Term, R t' t''
  ============================
   exists f : nat -> Term, forall n : nat, R (f n) (f (n + 1))
```

With `transitive_closure` defined as follows:

```
Definition transitive_closure (trs : TRS) (x y : Term) := 
    exists f: nat -> Term, 
            f 0 = x 
        /\ 
            exists l: nat, 
                    f l = y 
                /\ 
                    forall n: nat, 
                            n < l 
                        -> 
                            trs (f n) (f (n + 1))
.
```

So when I `unfold`:

```
  infinite_sequence : forall t' : Term,
                      (exists f : nat -> Term,
                         f 0 = t /\
                         (exists l : nat,
                            f l = t' /\
                            (forall n : nat, n < l -> R (f n) (f (n + 1))))) ->
                      exists t'' : Term, R t' t''
  ============================
   exists f : nat -> Term, forall n : nat, R (f n) (f (n + 1))
```

Is this proof obligation possible to fulfill? I am not married this exact definition of `transitive_closure`, so if it becomes much easier by choosing a different definition for that, I'm open to that.

Comment: My guess is that it should be possible to fulfill this, but you need to assume the axiom of choice. Intuitively, to build the function `f` you need to use the hypothesis to extract a term for each finite sequence of transitions. Since the term `t''` is existentially quantified in the hypothesis, you need choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your goal starts with `exists f : nat -> Term`, you have to explicitly build such a function. The easiest way to do so is to first build a function with a slightly richer return type (`{ u: Term | transitive_closure R t u }` instead of `Term`) and then to project pointwise its first component to finish the proof. This would give the following script:

```
simple refine (let f : nat -> { u: Term | transitive_closure R t u } := _ in _).
- fix f 1.
  intros [|n].
  { exists t. exists (fun _ => t). admit. }
  destruct (f n) as [t' H].
  destruct (infinite_sequence t' H) as [t'' H']. (* ISSUE *)
  exists t''.
  destruct H as [f' [H1 [l [H2 H3]]]].
  exists (fun m => if Nat.ltb m l then f' m else t'').
  admit.
- exists (fun n => proj1_sig (f n)).
  intros n.
  rewrite Nat.add_1_r.
  simpl.
  destruct (f n) as [fn Hn].
  now destruct infinite_sequence as [t'' H'].
```

The two `admit` are just there to keep the code simple; there is nothing difficult about them. The real issue comes from the line `destruct (infinite_sequence t' H)`, since Coq will complain that "Case analysis on sort Set is not allowed for inductive definition ex." Indeed, `infinite_sequence` states that there exists `t''` such that `R t' t''`, but it does so in a non-informative way (i.e., in `Prop`), while you need it to build a function that lives in the concrete world (i.e., in `Set`).

There are only two axiom-free solutions, but both might be incompatible with the remaining of your development. The easiest one is to put `infinite_sequence` in `Set`, which means its type is changed to `forall t', transitive_closure R t t' -> { t'' | R t' t'' }`.

The second solution requires `R` to be a decidable relation and `Term` to be an enumerable set. That way, you can still build a concrete `t''` by enumerating all the terms until you find one that satisfies `R t' t''`. In that case, `infinite_sequence` is only used to prove that this process terminates, so it can be non-informative.

Comment: This is probably the correct way, but I ended up rewriting some definition so I wouldn't need to give this proof. Nonetheless, thank you!